# Is it common to only find empty CS:GO servers?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I played CS:GO today and found that there were no servers, and it told me to increase the maximum ping requirement. I increased it from 150 to 200 and it found a server.

However, every single person in the server was a `BOT`

I hit the top option (the one that doesn't give you a warning about how community servers may not use the same models) of play multiplayer under the play button.

Comment: That's actually kinda creepy

Comment: @User1337 Why? ­

Comment: It's a ghost game o_O

Comment: So I assume it's not common?

Comment: Aint got CS:GO mate. I just noticed the answer. Good luck finding someone that knows wth's going on though.  P.S. this might be a start of a good creepypasta

Comment: for the past few days(or weeks, time flows funny at the end of the year) I've been mostly getting into the game with +-50% bots. Sometimes it was 1 or 2 bots, sometimes there were only 2 or 3 real players(including me). I could recommend trying out the `Community Servers`. If you go to the browsing section, you will find an old-style lovely server browser(as it was in *CS 1.6*, *CS:CZ* and *CS:S*). You may find some servers with real players there. But beware, there might be some custom mods on these servers, so it will be different that a "classic" CS.

Comment: Has this happened before? Will the regular servers pop back?

Comment: How do you increase your ping???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say that you do not find any server and after increasing your maximum ping, it is surely your internet connection.

Reason behind that is that, that the most players have it on 150ms. So the most of the players find a server. You dont find one because you need to much time for a ping.

So you should stop downloads or stop listeng to music that is streaming in the background like youtube.

You should set the maximum ping to 150ms otherwise the chance is higher to find a empty server (with Bots).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this depends on how many people play the game inside the country where you're living.
Also, your internet speed also decrease your chance finding a server that have people playing.

Comment: How does your internet speed decrease your chance of finding a server with people?

Comment: @Frank Many games will exclude people with slow connections from joining certain servers.

Comment: @ElfSlice And that's what I believe, since I've bought the game since when it's on beta.