# Every time I launch a game, I end up with bots

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've just bought cs global offensive and every time i launch a game, i end up with bots.

Is it normal? On steam the stats says that it's one of the most played games :/

Or am I doing something wrong??

Thanks for help =)

Comment: I don't own CS:Go, but a few things you could try are: Check your firewall settings (it should gives you a popup when starting a game if that's the problem), Make sure you are updated to the latest version of the game, Doublecheck in the menu if there is an option to play against players only.

Comment: It's weird because yesterday for about 1 min I've tested the game and ended up in a game with real players

Comment: hmm, it can hardly be any of those things then. Sorry, I can't help you further, I don't have the game and google gave me nothing relevant.

Comment: Your problem should be answerd with my answer in [this post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148379/is-it-common-to-only-find-empty-csgo-servers/152504#152504)

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually do my teams set up but when at the menu with your list of steam friends online in game, you can choose which you play there. I believe you want the 'competitive' matches or matchmaking.

Click Play > Find a Game or Community Quick Play or Play with Friends should all allow you to play with people.

If you are in Steams offline mode you might have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Click Play>Browse Community Servers and then pick a server with 10-15 people(or how ever many you desire) and no bots. Watch out for idle servers, trading servers, and servers with high ping or custom maps.